# Java Multi Thread communiction

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning multi-thread communication in Java. I came across a problem:

There are four threads T1, T2, T3, and T4. All of these threads are running, there is a condition 'C'. Whenever any of these four thread reaches there first, it will wait for another three threads.

For example, if thread T2 hits the condition 'C' it will wait for Threads T1, T3, and T4 unless they also hit condition 'C'. and then all threads will start again.

please let me know if you need more details..Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Clarification :  when i said they will start again. it means they will continue the execution.

Comment: I do not understand a negative vote for this. is anything wrong in my question ?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

A [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) does what you want. Just initialize it with the number of threads, and call `await()` at the meet-up point in each thread.

Comment: I cannot up-vote as of now. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a threadSafe object to share information, for example ConcurrentHashMap.Or you can you a simple static array to share, there is many ways to do that.